# Copy a column changing the name in Dbf

Tags: python, dbf

i have a dbf file with this scruture:

```
__SAMPLEID
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

I want to copy the values but change na column name, the result i expect is something like that:

```
__SAMPLEID       ID
  1              1
  2              2
  3              3
  4              4
```

i try to use dbfpy or db libs on python, its possible to do that?

Comment: So you want a new database with the same values as the original but different column names?

Comment: actually can be in the same database doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my [`dbf library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf):

To rename a field in an existing dbf:

```
import dbf

with dbf.Table('file-name-here.dbf') as table:
    table.rename_field('old_name', 'new_name')
```

To copy the table, giving a new name to certain fields:

```
import dbf

old_table = dbf.Table('original-table-here.dbf')
fields = old_table.structure()
# fields is a list of specifications, such as "name C(20)"
changes = [('field1', 'field10'), ('field2', 'field20')]
for old_name, new_name in changes:
    for i, f in enumerate(fields):
        if f.startswith(old_name + ' '): # note the space!
            fields[i] = f.replace(old_name, new_name)

new_table = dbf.Table('new_table_name_here.dbf', fields)
with old_table as old, new_table as new:
    for record in old_table:
        new_table.append(tuple(record))
```