# Invalid column name of DBF

Tags: python, dbf

I trying to read and edit a column name on my dbf name _sampleid, but he says the _sampleid is a invalid name of dbf:

Code:

```
#coding-utf-8
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, BOTH, Text, Menu, END
import tkFileDialog
#from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import dbf

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Conversor de Arquivo DBF.")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Abrir", command=self.onOpen)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Arquivo", menu=fileMenu)

        self.txt = Text(self)
        self.txt.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


    def onOpen(self):
        ftypes = [('All files', '*')]
        dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        fl = dlg.show()
        if fl != '':
            text = self.readFile(fl)
            self.txt.insert(END, text)

    def readFile(self, fl):
        text = "Seu arquivo foi convertido corretamente e pronto para carregar no InCeres. O mesmo se encontra na" \
               "mesma pasta que foi importado"
        text2 = "Nao foram encontrados ocorrencia para serem corrigidas."
        mudou = False

        with dbf.Table(fl) as table:
            for field in ('sampleid','_sampleid', 'n__samplei', 'N_SAMPLEID'):
                try:
                    table.rename_field(field.lower(), 'id')
                    mudou = True
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    pass

        if mudou:
            return text
        else:
            return text2




def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("300x250+300+300")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

> _sampleid invalid:  field names must start with a letter, and can only contain letters, digits, and _

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

My [`dbf module`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) doesn't allow leading underscores in field names.

A workaround for now would be to rename any such fields;  if you don't have control over the original field names I'll look at updating `dbf` to allow it.

---

Further digging shows the problem is in `backup()` -- when a field is renamed a backup as automatically generated, and that process is failing because of the leading underscore.

At this point it is not possible to skip the backup step (I'll work on that), nor does the backup process skip such validation checks (I'll work on that, too).

So for now, the only option is to use the other possibility in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40475724/208880):

- open the existing table
- grab the structure (as a list of field specifications)
- modify the structure to change any field names
- create a new, empty database using the new, modified structure
- copy over the data

Not an elegant solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Use [`the answer from yesterday`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40475724/208880) to rename the field.